# run exe with parameters in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0

Why are the arguments being ignored? The command ($re) is executed but none of the arguments are apparently supplied.

```
$re = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Y\RM 2010\RM.exe"
$arg1 = ' /W:"cross"'
$arg2 = ' /P:"C:\Users\P\Documents\RM\RM.rep"'
$arg3 = ' /U /S'

& $re $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
```

Comment: Probably worth reading this http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/

Comment: What happens if you try `&$re /W:"Cross" /P:"C:\Users\P\Documents\RM\RM.rep" /U /S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$re = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Y\RM 2010\RM.exe"
$arg1 = '/W:\"cross\"'
$arg2 = '/P:\"C:\Users\P\Documents\RM\RM.rep\"'
$arg3 = '/U'
$arg4 = '/S'
& $re $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
```

To get the `"` marks included in arg1 & arg2, they had to be escaped `\"`.

Don't know if the leading spaces on the parameters might of confused RM.EXE, but they should not be required.

Also, I split the `/U /S` as these look like separate parameters.

After running the above through ECHOARGS.EXE, the output is as follows:

```
Arg 0 is </W:"cross">
Arg 1 is </P:"C:\Users\P\Documents\RM\RM.rep">
Arg 2 is </U>
Arg 3 is </S>

Command line:
"H:\temp\EchoArgs.exe"  /W:\"cross\" /P:\"C:\Users\P\Documents\RM\RM.rep\" /U /S
```

Finally, if you are running PowerShell 3 (as per the tag), you should be able to make use of `--%`. This will force PowerShell send the remainder of the command line 'as-is'. e.g.

```
& $re --% /W:"cross" /P:"C:\Users\P\Documents\RM\RM.rep" /U /S
```

Can still do is in PS 1 or 2 by using the following form:

```
& $re /W:\`"cross\`" /P:\`"C:\Users\P\Documents\RM\RM.rep\`" /U /S
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm on Win 8.1 and actually PS 4.0. Echoargs is a good suggestion.